# How to change a form action using Javascript and Selenium in JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I've been trying to replace the action attribute of a form using javascript and selenium in JAVA, but I can't get it to work.

This is the site's snippet HTML:

```
</div>
<div class="contionue-shopping-wrapper">
<form class="co-formcontinueshopping" action="https://www.yahoo.com" method="post" id="dwfrm_cart_d0jilurhcxpm">
<fieldset>
<button class="rbk-button-red button-primary bp-black right" type="submit" value="Continue Shopping" name="dwfrm_cart_continueShopping">
<span>Continue Shopping</span>
</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

This is what I've done in JAVA in an attempt to change the action above

```
String link = "https://www.google.com"
((JavascriptExecutor)atc).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('co-formcontinueshopping')[0].action="+link);
```

(note: atc is the Selenium chrome webdriver and site is loaded at this stage)

EDIT: I think if I convert the following javascript to above it'll work?

```
document.getElementById(document.querySelector("[id^='dwfrm_cart']").id).action = url})()
```

Comment: log `document.getElementsByClassName('co-formcontinueshopping')[0].action` to the console to see if the selector works, using  `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('co-formcontinueshopping')[0].action)`

Comment: Please check comment on your answer below. Thanks

Comment: The problem is you don't have the `'` in your JavaScript. So you should either write String link = "'https://www.google.com'" or have the `'` in your JavaScript executed via the `JavascriptExecutor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should actually work, for example this code works:

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException{

    driver.get("https://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/Cart-Show");
    JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    String link = "'http://www.example.com'"; // notice the extra ' inside the "

    //log the current value of 'action'
    js.executeScript("console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('co-formcontinueshopping')[0].action)");

    //change the value to the value hold by our link
    js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('co-formcontinueshopping')[0].action=" + link);

    //log 'action' again
    js.executeScript("console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('co-formcontinueshopping')[0].action)");

    driver.quit();
}
```

And the output in the console of the browser is:

```
https://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/Cart-Show/C1360474325
http://www.example.com/
```

So the approach is right, only in your situation something must be missing such as:

- the `document.getElementsByClassName('co-formcontinueshopping')` is returning something wrong, this can have several causes, e.g. the site is in an `iframe`. Check if the correct element is returned, for example by logging it to the console.
- the `document.getElementsByClassName('co-formcontinueshopping')[0]` is returning something else as you expected, check that one too
- you are setting the action to something else then I did in my example, e.g. I used the `''`.
- something else, such as a different browser (I used Chrome 54.0.2840.98 on Mac)

Comment: I used this javascript instead: console.log(document.getElementById(document.querySelector("[id^='dwfrm_cart']").id).action) and it worked. How can I convert the selector in java, the " and ' are throwing me off. Thanks

Comment: and how can I set the action to a string variable that I created earlier.

Comment: I have the code working here, I'll update my answer, 1 sec

Comment: Here you go, make sure you have the ' inside your " for the `link` string.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just checked. Works flawlessly! Thanks a lot. I still can't believe I forgot about the ' ' around the link.